# how to display form data in textarea in the same form before submit in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form with radio buttons and checkboxes. I have a textarea before submit i have to dispaly the selected radio and check box values in that textarea. Can you please help me in that concern.How to do it in jquery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery serializeArray method will return the data of all your form element in JSON format.

It will also query against the type of fields and return the data , for example ,

```
var fields = $(":input").serializeArray();
```

returns-

```
[
  {
    name: "customerName",
    value: "jhonny"
  },
  {
    name: "age",
    value: "29"
  },

  ]
```

will return the data of all input field in json format.You can parse the JSON string and display the data in your textarea.

[Jquery serialize API](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray)

Answer (score 0):

Get all the radios and checkboxes using the `:checked` psuedoselector. Then use an each statement and append their values to a textbox.

http://jsfiddle.net/hPsHb/2

```
$(':checkbox, :radio').change(function() {
    //clear textarea
    $('textarea').val('');

    //for every checked element
    $(':checked').each(function() {
        var $textarea = $('textarea');
        $textarea.val($textarea.val() + $(this).prop('name') + ' = ' + this.value + '\n' );
    });
});​
```

Comment: here i dont need any buttons to click when the user checks the radio button at that moment that value should be displayed in the textarea.If he selects the value previously for one question and now he corrects it it should be rewrited on the old one

Comment: @ramsai - bind to the change event of all checkboxes and radios then. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: hi mrtsherman, Thank you for your reply but i need some information to be added to this. For example if a radio button has values 1,2,3 then if you click one then in the textarea should be:            youclicked'1' option                                                        Can you please tell me how to do this one .Thank s in advance

Comment: You are going to have to read up on this stuff, I'm not your personal web developer. Last bit of help on this one. If you have further questions you should ask a new question on SO or google the answer. Just give the radio buttons the same name if you want to toggle between them. http://jsfiddle.net/hPsHb/7/